# No such file or directory - bash

Tags: command-line, scripts, music

I am running out of ideas (and sources of ideas) on this one. I am getting a file-path from Audacious, and trying to get album art from the directory referenced. The info provided is correct, and works in terminal.

Things I have tried:

1. Redirected variable to a file, and looked with hexedit for odd characters.
2. Checked script for odd characters the same way.
3. Executed the script with /bin/bash directly.
4. Made a new script with only the non-functional code.
5. Because the path returned is relative [~/Music/Eagles/Desperado] have tried it as [/home/freebird/Music/Eagles/Desperado].
6. Because [Music] is a soft link to another drive have tried it as [/mnt/data/Music/Eagles/Desperado]
7. Have been using the Eagles because I didn't want to deal with [~/Music/Alice Cooper/School's Out] until I had the simpler case working!
8. IT does not have any CR's or other extraneous characters from editing on Windows or elsewhere - haven't used Windows for anything but Freecell and Spider Solitaire since 2007.
9. Nothing so far can resolve the resulting path into usability from inside the script, ALL work from the terminal (including cd).

Here is the actual error message from a recent try:

```
freebird@nest:~$ ~/check.sh
/home/freebird/check.sh: line 8: cd: ~/Music/Eagles/Desperado: No such file or directory
```

Any further suspects for me?

Here is the check script for testing:

```
#!/bin/bash
file_path=`audtool --current-song-tuple-data file-path`
echo > test2 ${file_path}
#${file-path}="/mnt/data/""${file_path:2}"
echo > testpath ${file_path}
cd "${file_path}"
#cd -P "${file-path}"
pwd
exit 1
if [[ ! -e "folder.jpg" ]];   # if no art work found
    then
    cp ~/Work/headphone.png /tmp/cover.png # put in placeholder
    echo "Placeholder"
 else
    convert "${file_path}""/folder.jpg" -resize 120x120 /tmp/cover.png # ready for showing
    echo "found cover"
 fi
```

It contains various 'test' additions still, the equivalent of scattered printf() to see what's going on :)

new version of testing script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file_path=`audtool --current-song-tuple-data file-path`
file_path=$(eval echo $file_path)
echo > test2 ${file_path}
${file-path}="$HOME"${file_path:1}
echo > testpath ${file_path}
cd ${file-path}
#cd -P "${file-path}"
pwd
exit 1
if [[ ! -e "folder.jpg" ]];   # if no art work found
    then
    cp ~/Work/headphone.png /tmp/cover.png # put in placeholder
    echo "Placeholder"
 else
    convert "${file_path}""/folder.jpg" -resize 120x120 /tmp/cover.png # ready for showing
    echo "found cover"
 fi
```

New error messages:

```
freebird@nest:~$ ~/check.sh
/home/freebird/check.sh: line 5: path=/home/freebirdhome/freebird/Music/Eagles/Desperado: No such file or directory
/home/freebird/check.sh: line 7: cd: path: No such file or directory
/home/freebird
freebird@nest:~$
```

Comment: `~` character inside double quotes is not expanded; use `$HOME` or remove the double quotes around `${file_path}`.

Comment: Tried both quote removal (added originally for space and ' character handling) and tried $HOME (separately and together). Same errors, same places.

Comment: The error message says that `~/Music/Eagles/Desperado` does not exit, which I suppose is correct since there is probably no directory with name `~` (the single character tilde) in the current directory. If you expect the `~` character to be expanded, the error message should be mentioning about a file `/home/your_user/Music/...`.

Comment: Here are actual error msgs:/home/freebird/check.sh: line 4: path=/home/freebird/Music/Eagles/Desperado: No such file or directory
/home/freebird/check.sh: line 6: cd: ~/Music/Eagles/Desperado: No such file or directory

Comment: Hope you can decipher that - no code block!

Comment: Can you add `file_path=$(eval echo $file_path)` before the first `echo` in the script?

Comment: Tried it - no change in output. (except line number of error are +1) You noted the diff between file_path and file-path? file-path is after mods to remove ~

Comment: I am skipping the comments. What `file-path` are you talking about? Can you update the script contents in your original question?

Comment: Delete line 5 (`${file-path}="$HOME"${file_path:1}`); it is of no use. Replace `file-path` with `file_path` in the `cd` statement.

Comment: Line 5 `${file-path}="$HOME"${file_path:1}` syntax looks wrong to me. Try `file-path="$HOME"${file_path:1}`?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the `audtool --current-song-tuple-data file-path` command returns a string which starts with `~`. You have to expand this string so that the `~` character will be replaced with your home folder. One method is this:

```
file_path=$(eval echo $file_path)
```

Please, insert the above statement just after the line running `audtool ...`.

Also, delete line 5

```
${file-path}="$HOME"${file_path:1}
```

it is of no use. Replace `file-path` with `file_path` in the `cd` statement.

Comment: I did that and no change anywhere noted. I'll try to edit/insert the relevant portion of script and errors in orig msg.

Comment: If you put `ls -ld "$file_path"` after my statement does it display anything useful?

Comment: drwxrwxr-x 2 freebird freebird 4096 May 18 09:47 /home/freebird/Music/Eagles/Desperado
                   is what it added. Sorry if slow! I dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04, should I try it there to see if different? (have same Music drive accessible there too)

Comment: I tried a few more things as suggested. It seems to be more functional now. I guess I got carried away with quotes :) on removal of file-path, it worked with file_path used. Quotes needed only on cd command and building the convert command. Hope it can handle stray ' chars too! Thanks all - now how do I mark it resolved?

Comment: Just click the gray up arrow (small triangle “▲”) at the left top of the answer and the gray check mark below.

Comment: Errors appeared to come from evaluations made before usage. Commenting out attempts to expand, or rereference to hard-coded names (/mnt/data/  or  /home/freebird/ killed off the error messages.